# Is it possible to open a URL after user sent to update browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I want to develop a new HTML5 / CSS3 webApp, and i need the users to have certain browsers compatible with specific CSS3 properties.

i wish to send users that have old browser versions to update them and after they update to reopen the Link to my webApp Automatically.

is there a way to do it?
Best for Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome...

Thanks,

IDan

Comment: Updating a piece of software like a browser is no consistent process across operating systems. Don’t waste time with this – and trust those of your users that are actually willing to update their browser just because your web app is asking for it to find their way back to your app themselves after doping so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `modernizr` to check if required HTML5/CSS3 features are enabled in the browser, if not display a disclaimer in your site to ask your user to upgrade (but the upgrade process must be done from your user, you can't force anything).

You can download custom version of Modernizr for the features you want to detect.

Docs: http://modernizr.com/docs/

Download: http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i dont need the detection solution. I need to know if there's a way to keep the same open after the upgrade, same as in chrome, in which you can upgrade and still have your tabs open. thanks again, IDan

Comment: Chrome implements that feature (and depends on users preferences) not the opened sites, so I think you have no way. The only is the suggested, ask user to update and eventually ask them to bookmark your site.